# VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS wrong information

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I am using the `DeviceIoControl` Windows function using the `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` to find out which partitions each volume is using. I am getting the data using that function and then checking each volume's extents which reside on the disk I'm interested in.

According to this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363968(v=vs.85).aspx

The returned data should state each extent's offset in bytes from the beginning of the disk, and its length in bytes. However it seems that the information I'm getting is wrong.

The physical disk I'm interested in is `500105249280` bytes long. However the data I got from `DeviceIoControl` states that one of the volumes resides on an extent at offset `499210256384` with length `896532480`. This puts the end of the extent at offset `500106788864` which is clearly past the end of the disk.

This seems to conflict with the documentation linked above. Can anyone tell me if I'm missing something else? Or is this an issue with my PC somehow?

Comment: How did you determine the size of the physical disk?  Have you tried, e.g., reading a sector from the disk at the offset in question and comparing it to the first sector read from the volume?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was getting the disk size wrong. I changed my code to retrieve the disk size using IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO with DeviceIoControl and now it seems to be working properly